# How to prove that $\sin(x)$ is continous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I want to prove that $\sin(x)$ is continous in $\mathbb R$, the definition that I have of $\sin(x)$ is the definition of the Spivak's book (the geometric one), but maybe using some other definition would make   the prove easier?

Comment: Which definition is used in Spivak? The geometric one? If you have that and the addition formula, then you know $|\sin(x+h)-\sin(x)| \leq |\sin(x)(\cos(h)-1)|+|\cos(x)\sin(h)| \leq |\sin(x)(\cos(h)-1)|+|h|$. So the only difficulty is controlling the first term. In fact you can be even blunter: $|\sin(x+h)-\sin(x)| \leq |\cos(h)-1|+|h|$. So the problem just reduces to showing $\cos$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: Please *state* the definition, since not everyone in the world uses the same text books.

Comment: Yes, the geometric one.